# navigation.getParam is not a function

Tags: react-native

I have a problem when getting value. It always returns me an error `navigation.getParam` is not a function.

Account.js

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail_Account', 
     {id:'hello'})}>
   <Block style={ styles.content }></Block>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

in my Detail Account

```
const { navigation } = this.props;  
const id = navigation.getParam('id', 'empty')   
    return(
        <Block>
            <Text>
                {id}
            </Text>
        </Block>
     );
```

Suggest any solution for this.

Comment: Which reactnavigation version are you using ?

Comment: i am using version 4.3.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Go to your `package.json` file in your project.

2) Change the version of `@react-navigation/stack` to a `5.x.x`.

Example:

```
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.14",
```

3) Run `npm install`.

4) Edit your `DetailAccount.js` as follows.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { Block, Text } from 'galio-framework';

class DetailAccount extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const id = this.props.route.params.id;

    return (
      <Block>
        <Text>{id}</Text>
      </Block>
    );
  }
}

export default DetailAccount;
```

5) Run `npm start` and restart your project.

You will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this...

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
const id = navigation.state.params.id;

return (
  <Block>
    <Text>{id}</Text>
  </Block>
);
```

**UPDATE**

When configured the whole code of `DetailAccount.js`, the problem was, `props` are not received in to the particular component. So, the components doesn't know what `this.props` is.

Please update your `DetailAccount.js` as follows.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { Block, Text } from 'galio-framework';

class DetailAccount extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const id = this.props.navigation.state.params.id;

    return (
      <Block>
        <Text>{id}</Text>
      </Block>
    );
  }
}

export default DetailAccount;
```

That means, simply you have to add the below part to your `DetailAccount` commponent.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}
```

Comment: its return me an error again "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.state.params')

Comment: Account.js is a screen or something like a Modal?

Comment: another layouts

Comment: Can you please tell me, have you included like <Account /> in somewhere in a render()? That means, you open Account JS rather than navigating to Account JS from a previous page?

Comment: can you help me?im new in react native

Comment: I know what the problem is. But, I need to see your code to configure how the problem is occurred.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215635/discussion-between-hafiz-ardi-and-sennen-randika).

Answer (score 0):

### **Try this solution**

#### Account.js

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() =>
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Detail_Account", { id: "hello" })
  }
>
  <Block style={styles.content}></Block>
</TouchableOpacity>;
```

#### Detail Account

```
const { id } = this.props.route.params;
return (
  <Block>
    <Text>{id}</Text>
  </Block>
);
```